# C Programming Calling pointer's pointer

Tags: c

I have these structs defined:

```
typedef struct {
  char *first_name;
  char *last_name;
  char SSN[9];
  float gpa;
  struct student *next;
} student;

typedef struct {
    student *head;
    student *current;
    student *tail;
} students;
```

In my main function, I want to add a student in the students struct. And then, call the first_name of head student. How do I do that?

```
void add(students *list, student *a) {
    if(list->head) {
        a->next = NULL;
        list->head = &a;
        list->current = list->head;
        list->tail = NULL;
    } else {
        printf("Will implement");
    }
}

int main()
{
    students grade1;

   student a;
   a.first_name = &"Misc";
   a.last_name = &"Help";

   add(&grade1, &a);

   printf("%s %s", a.first_name, a.last_name);
   printf("%s", grade1.head->first_name);
}
```

printf("%s", grade1.head->first_name);

Doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `Doesn't seem to work.` what not work? what you want? is this code compile? be specific about your issue.

Comment: Aren't you getting a warning about incorrect types on the line `list->head = &a;`? And if the new student is put at the head of the list, don't you need to set something to the old head of the list so you don't lose it?

Comment: I want grade1.head->first_name to return Misc

Comment: Shouldn't you initialize `grade1` before using it in the call to `add()`...?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to initialize all data members of object `grade1`. For example

```
students grade1 = { 0 };
```

Secondly instead of

```
student a;
a.first_name = &"Misc";
a.last_name = &"Help";
```

there should be at least like

```
student *a = malloc( sizeof( student ) );
a->first_name = "Misc";
a->last_name = "Help";
a->next = NULL;
```

Function `add` could look like

```
void add( students *list, student *a ) 
{
    if ( list->tail == NULL )
    {
        list->head = list->tail = a;
    }
    else
    {
        list->tail->next = a;
    }
}
```

And it can be called as

```
add( &grade1, a );
```